# Markdown list not terminating

Tags: markdown

I'm creating a readme.md file for one of our repo's to help some new people and having some trouble with lists.

The list prints out correctly, but all text following the list prints out as if it were part of the last item on the list (it is indented, entire sections). The lines preceeding the list are not indented and have no trailing white space. Can anyone help me understand why this is behaving like this?

Code:

```
## Typical Workflow Example
* Make LOCAL changes 
* Add any new files
    git add <file1, file2, ..., filen>
* Double-check files are modified/added/removed
    git status
* Commit changes
    git commit -a -m "Commit message"
* Push changes to remote
    git push origin <branchname>

- - - -

## Steps to Release New binary
* Make all changes
```

Output:

```
## Typical Workflow Example
* Make LOCAL changes 
* Add any new files
    git add <file1, file2, ..., filen>
* Double-check files are modified/added/removed
    git status
* Commit changes
    git commit -a -m "Commit message"
* Push changes to remote
    git push origin <branchname>

    - - - -

    ## Steps to Release New binary
    * Make all changes
```

As you can see, the horizontal line and beginning of next section is all tabbed as if it were part of the list.

Is there a manual way to terminate my lists?

Answer (score 4):

Normally blank space should terminate the list. I don't see any reason it wouldn't here, and without seeing the actual page it's hard to know why this is happening.

> Is there a manual way to terminate my lists?

Try putting an HTML comment (`<!-- -->`) after your list. That works well for separating two adjacent lists, e.g. to restart numbering:

```
1. One
1. Two

<!-- -->

1. One
1. Two
```