# Restart numbering of an ordered list in raw Markdown

Tags: markdown

I'm writing notes for a linear algebra course using Jupyter notebooks so that I can create graphs with matplotlib. Within a single Markdown cell, I'd like to have multiple ordered lists, all starting from 1. However, when I try to create the second ordered list, the numbering continues where the last list left off:

```
Consider the following system:
$$Ax = \begin{bmatrix}2&1&1 \\ 4&-6&0 \\ -2&7&2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}5\\-2\\9\end{bmatrix} = b$$
The following transformations of $A$ provide the triangular system $U$:
1. Subtract $2$ times the first equation from the second
2. Subtract $-1$ times the equation from the third
3. Subtract $-1$ times the second equation from the third
$$Ux = \begin{bmatrix}2&1&1 \\ 0&-8&-2 \\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\\w\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}5\\-12\\2\end{bmatrix} = c$$
Let us refer to the steps $1$, $2$, and $3$ as $E$, $F$, and $G$ respectively. Because the identity matrix is the equivalent of multiplying by $1$ in linear algebra, we can see that the transformations of each step can be viewed upon the template of an identity matrix:
1. Subtract $2$ times the first equation from the second: $\begin{bmatrix}1&&\\-2&1&\\-1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$
```

[image: Linear algebra notes]

The second list continues with `4` instead of restarting with `1`. How can I restart numbering in raw Markdown?

Comment: "Raw Markdown" doesn't know anything about LaTeX. What is the actual implementation you're using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown list not terminating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254632/markdown-list-not-terminating)

Answer (score 0):

Use a horizontal rule (`---`, `***` or `___`).